# Hiding site title for Twentyfifteen sidebar on (responsive) desktop display size

Tags: css, responsive, theme-twenty-fifteen

I'd like to hide the site title that appears on the sidebar on a twentyfifteen theme WordPress website when viewing it in a desktop display, but have it show when the display is fitted for mobile or tablet view (and a dropdown hamburger menu shows instead of a sidebar).

Ideally, I'd like to accomplish this through CSS. I couldn't see any unique CSS id's or classes applied to the body when resizing from desktop to mobile, so I can't figure out a way to do something like;

```
.site-title { display: none; }
```

but have it apply in the desktop view only. Any suggestions on how I could accomplish this? I'm also open to solutions via adjusting the theme PHP files if need be (via a child theme).

Comment: Well I'd at least like to figure out why I'm getting downvotes for asking this question, so I know better for the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it for you.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 59.6875em){
  .site-title {
     display: none;
  }
}
```

I'm new here so I'm not sure why the downvotes.

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you so much for your help!